# default gateway based on IP?

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing

yesterday I decided to try something extra at my job (volunteered to do so)

I decided to manually add a computer and assign it a private ip address netmask and default gateway. On a normal at home computer, i know you can just go to the cmd prompt and  see the gateway there.

however, I added a gateway from a printer in a office accross the room. Turned out the gateway where that printer is supposed to go was different.

I am wondering how are gateway addresses different per a subnet?

example room one is an address of 111.111.200.x
the other room is an address of   111.111.150.x

that is the only information I have. so how is it possible to find the gateway and subnet mask?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not 100% technically accurate, but simplified to match the target audience.

---

You should look into the basics of networking and routing, but a quick summary is as follows:

A network is a collection of hosts in a single broadcast domain. All these hosts share the same network address, subnet mask and gateway. For example:

```
Network address: 111.111.200.0
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 111.111.200.254
```

If you combine the network address and the subnet mask in a bitwise manner you get a range of IP addresses, for this example:

```
Start IP: 111.111.200.0 - 111.111.200.255
```

The first and last IP's are reserved for technical network purposes. All IP addresses from 1 - 254 can be used for hosts.

If a computer wants to send information to a host on it's network, it can directly send this information to the host.

However, if it wants to send information to a host outside of it's own network (so an IP that is *not* in the range 111.111.200.0 - 111.111.200.255), it has to use a gateway. The gateway will *route* the packets to the destination network because it's connected to both, or to networks that are connected to the destination network, as you can see in the image below:
[image: example network image]

If a computer with IP 192.168.8.2 wants to send information to 192.168.7.4, it will have to send the information to it's gateway which will forward the information to the right network and host.

As you can see, the netmasks and gateways are arbitrary and can be set up at the discretion of the network admin. More often than not, networks in offices and such have a netmask of 255.255.255.0 and the gateway has the first or last usable host address in the network (so .1 or .254), but this doesn't have to be the case. So these things can differ between networks.

The easiest way to find such details of a network is to ask the network admin. If you are unable to do that, you can see if there is a DHCP server active on the network. If there is, request a lease from it and it will tell you the network settings. If there is also no DHCP server on the network, you could check the network settings on a different computer on the same network.

If neither of these approaches work, guess and try.

Answer (score 0):

Will the printer get an IP address, default gateway and netmask when it's set up for DHCP?

If so, then that is it's default gateway for the network to which it is physically connected; manually configuring it with a different network's parameters will, in most cases, result in a connection.

If the printer is wired to the same LAN as the other office's network (I won't speak to WiFi; WiFi connections almost exclusively use DHCP), and doesn't receive a DHCP parameters, then its gateway may be determined by examining the network parameters of another device connected to that network.  Note that if you manually configure an IP address on the printer that is already in use by another system on that network, it will cause problems for both devices, even if it seems to work at first.

---

### Is there not a network administrator for this network?  It's usually courteous to involve the network administrator in such reconfiguration activities, regardless of whether the position of network admin is formal, or voluntary.

Finally, for a given network, A.B.C.x, with a netmask of 255.255.255.0, the default gateway IP is most often A.B.C.1, occasionally A.B.C.254, and rarely anything else, though x technically could be any number greater than 0, less than 255, it's usually 1.  The reader's mileage may vary. Use at your own risk.